# Need to read value from other config file

Tags: shell, file, key, config

I want to read value from another config file and need to store in variable

threshold --> is variable

config file contains below value

key=value x=2 y=70 z=20 d=10

if key=2 then threshold=2 if key=y then threshold=70 like above I want to print in threshold variable. Could you please advise?

Comment: So this is the literal content of the config file? It says that some identifier x is associated with the number 2. You seem to have a variable named _key_. What is the rule that the number you are seeking, is 2 and not i.e. 20 or 10? In any case plese post your own code for solving the problem, and explain at which point you are stuck.

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Comment: tried with some other way it working now. Need suggestion for below issue  thresholdvalue=$HOME/thresholdvalue.cfg
THRESHOLD=$(cat $thresholdvalue | grep $eventtype | cut -d'=' -f2)
if [ $RecordCount -gt $THRESHOLD ]

Getting below error while comparing from in IF 
: integer expression expected: line 91: [: 4